# Replacing double gang light switch

Tags: replacement

I’m wanting to replace my current light switch with a new more modern one. New one has wire holes for 1, C, 2. The switch is for new seperate lights. Which wires go where on the new light switch?

[image]

Comment: Your location in the world will help.   I will guess that red is hot and jumps to second switch.  The white and blue should be marked as switch hots/lives and go to different lights/receptacles.

Comment: I’m in New Zealand. The new switches are marked with 1, C and 2. I’m guessing the red wires go to 1 and the others go to a C on each switch?